# Commands /etc/init/boot.local get started before some environment variables get initialized

Tags: boot, startup, environment-variables, shell-scripting, init.d

*I have OpenSuse 11.4.*

I start some on-boot scripts inside `/etc/init/boot.local`.

Where could I move those scripts so that they would be started after all (most) environment variables got initialized?

These scripts need to be started really *once*, so things such as `/etc/profile.local` aren't candidates.

I try to start Sonar, which searches for Java in some strange way (instead just by look up `JAVA_HOME`), and it fails to find Java (logs don't tell me exactly why). From command line, after boot, it *can* be started (as root and as user).

*I suppose, there are some environment variables which get initialized inside services. Can it be that way?*

**EDIT: [sonar.sh from sonar/bin/linux-x86-64](http://pastebin.com/PFq2NSMy)**
**EDIT: [sonar.log from sonar/logs](http://pastebin.com/k8EkGVCg)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with openSUSE, but in my opinion, the best way is export the environment variables before starting the services in `/etc/init/boot.local`.

---

**EDIT**

> Unable to start JVM: No such file or directory

Does JAVA_HOME/bin/ is already in your PATH?

Comment: Well, as I sad, I don't know *how* Solar is searching for Java. It's *not* `JAVA_HOME` or other well-known variables, because they *are* set early enough.

Comment: Could you please post the init script for Solar?

Comment: @quenta done, edited question

Comment: What error you get when starting `sonar.sh`?

Comment: @quante see 2nd edit: log messages, such as "wrapper started as daemon", do not appear inside the script pasted before.

Comment: Insert `export JAVA_HOME=...` and `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` into `start()` function and try again.

Comment: Well, it seems that it was `$JAVA_HOME/bin`, I just added the line `. /etc/profile.local` right before `sonar.sh` inside `/etc/init.d/boot.local` and now it works! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Normally global variables are not initialized in init-scripts. The variables you need get propably initialized in your shell by /etc/profile.local or some other shell-configuration file.

If a java is being found from the shell where is it located?

Comment: In general, for init scripts either use the fully qualified path to the executable and setup the exact environment variables you need.